# SQL Server: set variable value using stored procedure (from one to another)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where I am taking all the input parameter values and then within that stored procedure I am running another stored procedure where I need to set a variable value.

I am not sure how to set a variable of child stored procedure using parent stored procedure. Also, output of parent stored procedure is not the input of child stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_aStoredProcedure_1]
    @sp1_var char(12),
    @sp1_var char(12),
    @sp1_var char(12),
    ...     
    @sp2_var char(20)

AS
CREATE TABLE #aTemp_tbl
(
    col1 char(20)
)

CREATE TABLE #Results_tbl
(
    col1 char(20),
    val1 char(12)
)
IF @val1 IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM #aTemp_tbl
        INSERT INTO #aTemp_tbl EXEC usp_aStoredProcedure_2 @val1 /* this stored procedure requires @sp2_var value, how can I assign it within this usp_aStoredProcedure_1 stored procedure?*/
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #aTemp_tbl)            
            INSERT INTO #Results_tbl SELECT NULL, @val1
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO #Results_tbl SELECT col1 , @val1 FROM #aTemp_tbl
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass value to child stored procedure like you are doing for parent stored procedure...

Comment: I have tried, but c# code says that parent stored procedure has too many argument. can you give syntax pls

Comment: @user1889838 andrey gave you example

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly set a **variable** of child stored procedure from parent stored procedure. You must use the **parameters** of child procedure for that.

See example below:

```
-- child procedure
create procedure p1
    @param1 varchar(4),
    @param2 varchar(4)
as
begin
    select @param1 + @param2;
end;

-- parent procedure
create procedure p2
    @param1 varchar(2),
    @param2 varchar(2)
as
begin

    declare
        @param3 varchar(4),
        @param4 varchar(4);

    select
        @param3 = @param1 + '_x',
        @param4 = @param2 + '_x'

    -- setting parameters of child stored procedure using parent stored procedure
    exec p1 @param3, @param4;
end;

-- call parent procedure
exec p2 '1', '2'
```